# Application loader error

Tags: iphone, ios, code-signing, provisioning-profile

This app contains an embedded provisioning profile that is not associated with your account. Please use a provisioning profile associated with team ID : I am getting this error while I upload the build with Application loader.

I am using two different accounts. 
1) For creating provisioning profile 
2) For uploading in iTunes.

Everything had worked fine till date. I have updated my app several times in app store. I am using the same procedure but facing this issue.

What might be the reason? Its an emergency Please help me on this.

Comment: The possiblity is that you may use the developer provisional profile instead of distribution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I Think i have cracked this issue, But dont know if there is still a better solution.

As i used a different accounts for creating provisioning profile and submitting it in iTunes, because of which i got this error.

Solution: We have to use the same account for creating the provisioning profile and also submitting it in iTunes. As a trial i did the same, it just worked fine.

Answer (score 2):

Apple does not allow anymore submission of an app on a developer account if this app have been signed using a different developer account certificate (different team ID).

You have no other choice than sign you app with the developer account certificate where you want the submission to be done. If the Bundle ID is already taken on the other/previous developer account, you will have to sign your app using a wildcar mobile provision.

If you need push notif or Game Center or anything that need to avoid a wildcar AppStore mobile provision, then you are in trouble => setup a brand new app (new app ID / Bundle ID) and plan migration of your customers from the old app to the new one ...

See [Here](http://blog.hoachuck.biz/blog/2012/12/04/use-a-provisioning-profile-associated-with-team-id/)

Answer (score 0):

I have finally updated my app to app-store successfully!

Reason:

Actually we had an corporate account and an individual developer account. Before we use to update using the individual account, Since the Apple Licence agreement changed some time back.
We cannot upload or update your app with the individual account if it is connected with the corporate account.

Soln:

Need to add or link the individual account to corporate account.